# Personnel costs recorded twice in the income statement?

Tags: accounting, bookkeeping, income-statement, theory

We are talking about a company that produces its own products. Since the manufacturing costs also include part of the personnel costs, the personnel costs are recorded twice in the income statement. On the one hand, in the share for the production of the product in the cost of goods and on the other hand, the normal wage costs in the personnel costs. Do you know where I can find literature on the proper accounting of these business transactions?

Answer (score 2):

This accounting-training site provides some example data and everything:

`https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/knowledge/accounting/wage-expense/`

Bottom line - every dollar of wages paid is *either* reported in the personnel costs section *or* the Production section.. not both.

Valid accounting principles universally prohibit reporting any expense twice on an income/expense report, whether you're talking about GAAP, IRS guidelines, Federal Accounting Regulations, or any other regulation framework.

Here is a search of the CFR (Code of Federal Regulations) on wages:

`https://www.ecfr.gov/search?flag=invalid_reference&search%5Bquery%5D=wages`

There are 2200 results, so.